# How to connect DisplayPort signals respectively for sink and source applications?

Tags: usb, schematics, design, usb-c, displayport

I am using the TPS65988 PD controller and TUSB546A-DCI for USB TYPE C with alternate mode application. I am a little bit confused about how to connect DisplayPort signals respectively.

Firstly I found this diagram:
[image: DisplayPort Wiring Diagram]

In the TPS65988EVM schematic:
[image: TPS65988EVM schematic DisplayPort]

When I place the same DP connector found in Altium Manufacturer Part Search:
[image: DP connector found in Altium Manufacturer Part Search]

As you can see in the pictures above, DP connector pin 1 is named ML0_P in Altium Library and ML3_N in TPS65988EVM schematic.
At first, I thought I need to cross DisplayPort signals respectively (ML0_P => ML3_N), but then I messaged a TI Guru on the TI forum and he said you don't need to cross DP signals. But TI also crossed signals as shown on the evm schematic pin1 to ML3_N. So I am confused about what to do and couldn't find any documents about crossing on the internet.

So how can I connect DisplayPort signals according to my application?

Comment: re. the 25 pin connector ... pins 21-24 are the mounting solder tabs on the connector shell

Comment: I am asking for the signal names.

Comment: the cable does the crossing ... you decide if the device is a source or a sink ... the schematic shows J5 wired as a sink

Comment: Thank you so much!